# Problema con el renderizado de un .map en reactjs

Tags: reactjs

acabo de terminar un curso de React y para practicar estoy realizando una Pokedex utilizando la API de pokeAPI. Sin embargo, cuando intento renderizar la lista de pokemones, estos no aparecen.
Aqui tengo el codigo que hace la peticion a la api:

```
useEffect(() => {
    let pokemones = [];
    fetch(`${URL}/pokemon?limit=50`)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {
        data.results.map((item) => {
            fetch(item.url)
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(data => {
                pokemones.push(data);
            });
        });
    })
    pokemones = pokemones.sort((a, b) => {
        return a.id - b.id;
    });
    setPokemonList(pokemones);
    setLoaded(true);
}, []);
```

La lista de pokemones se pasa a un componente que recibe la lista y renderiza un componente PokeCard por cada item en el vector:

```
const PokedexScreen = ({ pokemonList }) => {
return (
  <div className='pokedex'>
    {
      pokemonList.map((pokemon, index) => {
        return (
          <PokeCard key={ index } pokemon={ pokemon } />
        )
      })
    }
  </div>
)}
```

Sin embargo, las cards no aparecen. me fije usando el React Developer Tools y, dentro del componente PokedexScreen aparece que la propiedad pokemonList contiene los items pero este no la renderiza, a veces aparecen pero inspeccionando los elementos no veo la diferencia entre cuando lo renderiza y cuando no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La lógica de tu `useEffect` es incorrecta. Estás intentando setear el valor de tu estado antes de que la petición haya sido resuelta. Tal y como está ahora mismo, la petición será inicializada y directamente pasará a setear el estado a un arreglo vacío. Cambia tu `useEffect` a algo como lo siguiente:

```
useEffect(() => {
    fetch("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?limit=50")
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => Promise.all(data.results.map(pokemon => fetch(pokemon.url))))
        .then(responses => Promise.all(responses.map(res => res.json())))
        .then(data => {
            let pokemones = data.sort((a, b) => {
                return a.id - b.id;
            });
            setPokemonList(pokemones);
            setLoaded(true);
            console.log(pokemones);
        })
}, []);
```

He realizado un pequeño demo que puedes probar desde acá:

```js
const {useState, useEffect } = React;
function App() {
    const [pokemonList, setPokemonList] = useState([]);
    const [loaded, setLoaded] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {;
        fetch("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?limit=10")
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(data => Promise.all(data.results.map(pokemon => fetch(pokemon.url))))
            .then(responses => Promise.all(responses.map(res => res.json())))
            .then(data => {
                let pokemones = data.map(pokemon => pokemon.sprites.front_default)
                setPokemonList(pokemones);
                setLoaded(true);
            })
    }, []);

    return (
        <div className='pokedex'>
            {
                loaded ?
                pokemonList.map((pokemon, index) => {
                    return (
                        <img key={index} src={pokemon} />
                    )
                })
                : "Loading..."
            }
        </div>
    )
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("app"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```